# How to stop my player from moving up to the sky when looking up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(A lil bit of context) the main camera is a child of the player.
Hello,
So i have this problem where when my character looks up the sky and if i press W, it is going to move up which is not I want so how do u stop this from happening, here is my code:

```cs
private void CalculateMovement() {   
    //Movement
    float _horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float _verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 _direction = new Vector3(_horizontalInput, 0, _verticalInput);
    Vector3 _velocity = _direction * _speed;
    _velocity = transform.transform.TransformDirection(_velocity);
    //Mouse Input and rotation
    float _mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float _mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
   
    Vector3 mouseInput = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x - 
        (_mouseY * _mouseSensititvity), transform.eulerAngles.y +
        (_mouseX * _mouseSensititvity), 0);
    transform.eulerAngles = mouseInput;  
   
    characterController.Move(_velocity * Time.deltaTime);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could simply eliminate any velocity on `y` **after** converting it to a world space vector like

```
_velocity = transform.transform.TransformDirection(_velocity);
_velocity.y = 0f;
```